# Determining the number of equilibrium points

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, system-limitations

Let's define the potential function $\Omega(x,y)$ of two magnetic dipoles

```
r1 = Sqrt[(x - 0.5)^2 + y^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x + 0.5)^2 + y^2];
p1 = 1/r1^3 + λ/r2^3;
q1 = 1/2*(1/r1^3 - λ/r2^3);
Ax = -y*p1;
Ay = x*p1 - q1;
Ω = ω*(x*Ay - y*Ax) + ω^2/2*(x^2 + y^2);
ω = 1;
```

Now the variable parameter $\lambda$, which is the ratio of the two magnetic moments, determines the total number of equilibrium points.

The positions of the equilibrium points on the $(x,y)$ plane are the solutions of the system

```
Ωx = D[Ω, x];
Ωy = D[Ω, y];
sol = NSolve[{Ωx == 0, Ωy == 0}, {x, y}]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica is not able to solve analytically this system. So after several trials with `FindRoot` I found that

- When $0 < \lambda < 2.6$  there are three equilibrium points
- When $2.6 < \lambda < 10.8$ there are seven equilibrium points
- When $\lambda > 10.8$ there are five equilibrium points

My question is the following: How can I use MMA to obtain the exact limits of the three intervals? For example, for the first case, 2.6 is only a first approximation (the same also applies for 10.8). I want the exact limits which accuracy of at least 6 or 8 decimal digits.

If `NSolve` was working then I could use it inside a DO or FOR loop in the interval $\lambda \in (0,20]$ with a sufficiently small step between the values of $\lambda$ and monitor the value of `Length[sol]`.

I use version 9.0 of MMA in Win XP SP3.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask how long you've tried to run the `NSolve[]`, and how much RAM you have? I doubt it's going to complete, but aborting after running it for five minutes gave `MaxMemoryUsed[]` over `4.5 GB Ram`. It's not encouraging, but it makes me want to run the code for half an hour just to see if something happens.

Comment: @Feyre I aborted after ten minutes of running. I have 4GB of RAM but it's pointless to run `NSolve[]` just for one value of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a rough idea what's going on, you can start with `ContourPlot` to see the equilibrium points:

```
λ = 2.7;
ContourPlot[{Ωx == 0, Ωy == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Actually looks like there are 9 of them when `λ = 2.7`.

To figure out when the number of equilibria changes, I'll use the pseudo-arclength continuation function `TrackRootPAL` I hacked together [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104578/is-there-any-predictor-corrector-method-in-mathematica-for-solving-nonlinear-sys/104694#104694).  Be sure to copy and run that.

First, locate an initial point with `FindRoot`:

```
init = FindRoot[{Ωx == 0, Ωy == 0}, {x, 0.4}, {y, 1.1}]
(* {x -> 0.319266, y -> 1.03165} *)
```

Then track this equilibrium with `TrackRootPAL`:

```
Clear[λ];
tr = TrackRootPAL[{Ωx, Ωy}, {x, y}, {λ, -1, 12}, 2.7, {x, y} /. init]
```

This returns four pairs of `InterpolatingFunction`s, each of which is an equilibrium.  It doesn't get all of them because they're not connected, but the second and third ones seem to have both of the turning points you're looking for.  Extract the endpoints and you're done:

```
(x /. tr[[2]])["Domain"]
(* {{2.57753, 10.8861}} *)
```

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function) on finding all roots in 2D might also be relevant.

Comment: `TrackRootsPAL` or `TrackRootPAL`? (Typo, I think.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oops, thanks, fixed that.

Comment: I cannot get the last output with the end points. I get only one pair of interpolating functions. Note that I use v9 of MMA.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I might have run into that once myself.  I put the notebook [here](https://github.com/cklausme/mathematica.stackexchange/blob/master/121851.nb) that worked for me.

Comment: I downloaded the file and opened it with MMA but it only contains numerous lines of code with no sense, at least for me...

Comment: Let me try putting it somewhere else.  Does [this](http://preston.kbs.msu.edu/mathematica.stackexchange/121851.nb) work?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that uses some amount of symbolic computation to find the values in `lambda` where the number of real roots might change. We'll start by "polynomializing", wherein radicals get replaced (after derivatives are taken; my mistake in a prior attempt was premature replacement). Also we enforce that the denominators (which are the radicals) not vanish, in part because it turns out that this makes the computation more tractable.

```
r1 = Sqrt[(x - 1/2)^2 + y^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x + 1/2)^2 + y^2];
p1 = 1/r1^3 + lam/r2^3;
q1 = 1/2*(1/r1^3 - lam/r2^3);
Ax = -y*p1;
Ay = x*p1 - q1;
w = 1;
omega = w*(x*Ay - y*Ax) + w^2/2*(x^2 + y^2);
dx = D[omega, x];
dy = D[omega, y];
exprs = {dx, dy};
reprules = {((x - 1/2)^2 + y^2)^pow_ :> 
    sqrt1^(2*pow), ((x + 1/2)^2 + y^2)^pow_ :> sqrt2^(2*pow)};
newexprs = 
 Join[Numerator[
   Together[exprs /. reprules]], {((x - 1/2)^2 + y^2) - 
    sqrt1^2, ((x + 1/2)^2 + y^2) - sqrt2^2, sqrt1*sqrt1r - 1, 
   sqrt2*sqrt2r - 1}]

(* Out[356]= {2 lam sqrt1^5 sqrt2^2 - 2 sqrt1^2 sqrt2^5 - 
  3 lam sqrt1^5 x + 8 lam sqrt1^5 sqrt2^2 x - 3 sqrt2^5 x + 
  8 sqrt1^2 sqrt2^5 x + 4 sqrt1^5 sqrt2^5 x - 12 lam sqrt1^5 x^2 + 
  12 sqrt2^5 x^2 - 12 lam sqrt1^5 x^3 - 12 sqrt2^5 x^3 - 
  6 lam sqrt1^5 y^2 + 6 sqrt2^5 y^2 - 12 lam sqrt1^5 x y^2 - 
  12 sqrt2^5 x y^2, -y (-4 lam sqrt1^5 sqrt2^2 - 4 sqrt1^2 sqrt2^5 - 
    2 sqrt1^5 sqrt2^5 + 3 lam sqrt1^5 x - 3 sqrt2^5 x + 
    6 lam sqrt1^5 x^2 + 6 sqrt2^5 x^2 + 6 lam sqrt1^5 y^2 + 
    6 sqrt2^5 y^2), -sqrt1^2 + (-(1/2) + x)^2 + 
  y^2, -sqrt2^2 + (1/2 + x)^2 + y^2, -1 + sqrt1 sqrt1r, -1 + 
  sqrt2 sqrt2r} *)
```

We will first eliminate the radicals and their corresponding "reciprocal" variables.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 gb = GroebnerBasis[
    newexprs, {y, x, lam}, {sqrt1, sqrt2, sqrt1r, sqrt2r}, 
    MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder];]

(* Out[285]= {3.370995, Null} *)

{LeafCount[gb], Length[gb], Variables[gb]}

(* Out[287]= {15063, 14, {lam, x, y}} *)
```

Now we further eliminate to get a polynomial in `{x,lam}`. This curve will provide information on where `lam` causes changes to the number of real roots.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 gb2 = GroebnerBasis[gb, {x, lam}, {y}, 
    MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder, 
    Method -> {"GroebnerWalk", "EarlyEliminate" -> True}];]

(* Out[293]= {243.295412, Null} *)
```

What I would like to do actually is project onto a "random" slice in `{x,y}` so as to avoid any multiplicity that might be caused by our polynomial ideal not being in general position with respect to those variables. I expect the computation for this might finish, eventually. Meanwhile we'll run with what we have. Next step is to factor this polynomial, and compute the discriminant with respect to `x` for each branch. This gives polynomials in the lone remaining variable, `lam`, and those roots tell us where the number of real solutions might change. We'll do the same for `{y,lam}` to compensate for the fact that we do not have a generic slice to use.

```
fax = Rest[FactorList[gb2[[1]]]][[All, 1]];
discrims = Map[Discriminant[#, x] &, fax];

dfax = Union[Flatten[Map[Rest[FactorList[#]][[All, 1]] &, discrims]]];

droots = 
 Sort[Select[lam /. Flatten[Map[NSolve, dfax], 1], 
   FreeQ[#, Complex] && # >= 0 &]]

(* Out[313]= {0., 0.000446813391218, 0.680281240425, 0.73027825509, 1., \
1.30193004233, 2.14792610778, 2.57753090135, 2.86648401594, \
26.3812585094, 251.834652303, 256.151387487} *)
```

The discriminant with respect to `y` seems to require higher precision to detect multiplicity (as opposed to "smearing" of the roots).

```
fax2 = Rest[FactorList[gb3[[1]]]][[All, 1]];
discrims2 = Map[Discriminant[#, y] &, fax2];
dfax2 = Union[
   Flatten[Map[Rest[FactorList[#]][[All, 1]] &, discrims2]]];
droots2 = 
 Sort[Select[
   N[lam /. 
     Flatten[Map[
       NSolve[SetPrecision[#, 105], WorkingPrecision -> 100] &, 
       dfax2], 1]], FreeQ[#, Complex] && # >= 0 &]]

(* Out[386]= {0., 0.000233318481801, 0.000467498717924, \
0.000477162234268, 0.00480684218769, 0.0111396092288, \
0.0168041689625, 1., 2.38393678977, 2.57753090135, 10.0094256228, \
10.1802337238, 10.6552511706, 10.6555003448, 10.8861003459} *)
```

Even at high precision we seem to get either multiple roots or pairs that are really close. We will treat them as multiple although one might require more careful analysis to be certain this is correct.

We now interleave all these candidate values in `lam` and form test values as midpoints between them.

```
allroots = 
 DeleteDuplicates[Union[Sort[Join[droots, droots2]]], 
  Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^(-3) &]

(* Out[391]= {0., 0.00480684218769, 0.0111396092288, 0.0168041689625, \
0.680281240425, 0.73027825509, 1., 1.30193004233, 2.14792610778, \
2.38393678977, 2.57753090135, 2.86648401594, 10.0094256228, \
10.1802337238, 10.6552511706, 10.8861003459, 26.3812585094, \
251.834652303, 256.151387487} *)

testvals = 
 Map[Mean, Partition[Join[allroots, {Last[allroots] + 1}], 2, 1]]
```

Now we plug into the original system, solve, and count distinct solutions (again using a heuristic to delete repeated roots).

```
AbsoluteTiming[rttable = Table[
   rts = Select[{x, y} /. NSolve[exprs /. lam -> tval, {x, y}], 
     FreeQ[#, Complex] &];
   DeleteDuplicates[rts, Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^(-3) &],
   {tval, testvals}]]

(* Out[395]= {577.785656, {{{1.5950821374, 0}, {-0.670836160842, 
    0}, {-0.349220244537, 0}}, {{-0.752025153432, 
    0}, {-0.292655165775, 0}}, {{1.59550536523, 0}, {-0.801320876299, 
    0}, {-0.262705739517, 0}}, {{1.60421196531, 0}, {-1.31286480677, 
    0}, {-0.0672120225349, 0}}, {{1.61361957949, 0}, {-1.50783287337, 
    0}, {-0.0222205053881, 0}}, {{1.6178765457, 0}, {-1.57281441808, 
    0}, {-0.00920764235853, 0}}, {{-1.67090514356, 0}, {1.62555107012,
     0}, {0.00891642076776, 0}}, {{-1.82605880574, 0}, {1.64120384062,
     0}, {0.0344271585535, 0}}, {{-1.94259193471, 0}, {1.65624750294, 
    0}, {0.0514697465522, 0}}, {{-1.98359530982, 0}, {1.66229686077, 
    0}, {0.0570935550114, 0}}, {{-2.02687670997, 0}, {1.66914254562, 
    0}, {0.0628373149645, 0}, {0.325677000646, 
    1.03842190544}, {0.325677000646, -1.03842190544}, {0.250557974044,
     0.877183259635}, {0.250557974044, -0.877183259635}}, \
{{-2.49697155003, 0}, {1.78071451361, 
    0}, {1.12400131454, -1.15294574761}, {1.12400131454, 
    1.15294574761}, {0.11496589108, 0}, {0.340924584285, 
    0.661003285334}, {0.340924584285, -0.661003285334}}, \
{{-2.80052390242, 0}, {1.8990098863, 0}, {1.79008669505, 
    0.566852785821}, {1.79008669505, -0.566852785821}, {0.14119667652,
     0}, {0.385695288042, 
    0.593827261442}, {0.385695288042, -0.593827261442}}, \
{{-2.82349934959, 0}, {1.90971223415, 
    0}, {1.84558477978, -0.440569515358}, {1.84558477978, 
    0.440569515358}, {0.143002574913, 
    0}, {0.388551360804, -0.58943507049}, {0.388551360804, 
    0.58943507049}}, {{-2.84807056321, 0}, {1.92144139396, 
    0}, {1.90572786458, 
    0.221064881734}, {1.90572786458, -0.221064881734}, \
{0.144908890819, 0}, {0.391533132056, 
    0.584823272325}, {0.391533132056, -0.584823272325}}, \
{{-3.29357297444, 0}, {2.18435245136, 0}, {0.175566547126, 
    0}, {0.434721093781, -0.513474928552}, {0.434721093781, 
    0.513474928552}}, {{-5.83188742882, 0}, {4.5113932992, 
    0}, {0.274662616966, 0}, {0.515726918191, 
    0.309598715165}, {0.515726918191, -0.309598715165}}, \
{{-6.98538849106, 0}, {5.65692970645, 0}, {0.299805585636, 
    0}, {0.524227461647, 
    0.264318802331}, {0.524227461647, -0.264318802331}}, \
{{-7.00743889897, 0}, {5.67889363478, 0}, {0.30022139446, 
    0}, {0.524334891521, 
    0.263593384214}, {0.524334891521, -0.263593384214}}}} *)

We'll see where the number of real roots changes.

    Map[Length, rttable]

    (* Out[396]= {3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5} *)
```

The changes occur at the 2nd, 3rd, 11th and 16th positions.

```
allroots[[{2, 3, 11, 16}]]

(* Out[400]= {0.00480684218769, 0.0111396092288, 2.57753090135, \
10.8861003459} *)
```

Are these first two real change points or numerical artifacts? Limited testing suggests the former. Moreover the test to delete duplicates may have removed nonduplicate `lam` vales in that small range, so perhaps that region bears closer scrutiny (if it is of physical interest, and if having 2 equilibria is physically meaningful).

Comment: Can you give a summary of what `Method -> {"GroebnerWalk", "EarlyEliminate" -> True}` does?

Comment: It implements the "sudden death" strategy of Amrhein, Gloor, and Küchlin. Useful in situations where you happen to know it will work.

Comment: [This one](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(97)00064-9)? How does this compare to [Tran's](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jsco.1999.0416)?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that sudden death (Tran does not have a sudden death option). If you refer to whether to use of AGK's heuristic perturbation vs. Tran's deterministic one, then we use the former. Originally when Tran implemented the walk in Mathematica, it used the deterministic one.  Later we made the walk the default method for computing lex GBs and things started hanging due to exponent vectors with millions of digits. So I switched to use small perturbations at beginning and end. More info [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228381508_Implicitization_via_the_Grobner_Walk)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. Is there a complete list (or at least more information) of the available GB method? 
I have checked `SystemOptions["GroebnerBasisOptions"]`, but it only returns `{"GroebnerBasisOptions" -> {"EliminateFromGroebnerBasis" -> True, 
   "SyzygyCriterionLevel" -> 2, "UseGroebnerTrace" -> Automatic}}`.

Comment: @user688486 I’m not aware of any resource beyond links noted here. I don’t think I ever change the system option settings in my own usage. If I recall correctly there are further suboptions for when the walk is used. I’ll see if I can dig those up.

Comment: the Groebner walk code has options also used in `GroebnerBasis`. Also there are some options for specifying what initial term order to use (`"InitialMonomialOrder"`, default `DegreeReverseLexicographic`), whether to use perturbations to get to the final cone (`"Perturbation`", default `True`), the `"EarlyEliminate"` noted in this thread, and a few more I do not remember very well that involve strategies along the way.