# Finding smooth root sets to a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve for the roots of an equation like

$f(a, n) = \frac{n^2}{n+1} e^{i a n }$

for some list of complex $f$ values. For each $f$ value I know the (real) value of $a$, and I'd like to find an $n$ (complex) that satisfies. The catch is, I would like output list of $n$ values to have "smooth" real and imaginary parts. That is, plotting $n(a)$ I would see no "jumps" from one branch of solutions to another.

I've seen a number of related posts around here already about [continuous phase unwrapping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/implementing-continuous-phase-arg-function), [collecting transcendental equations' roots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80649/finding-roots-of-transcendental-equation-and-collecting-into-a-list), and [plotting branching functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26736/transcendental-equation-with-contourplot3d?noredirect=1&lq=1). But here I'd like to ask more specifically about finding the roots in a smooth, possibly iterative way.

My attempt at a solution is to search for a root starting at previous root, making it more difficult for `FindRoot[]` to jump away:

```
 smoothFindRoot[
  list_,
  list2_, 
  function_, 
  initialApproximation_] := First@Last@Reap@
     For[i = 1, i <= Length@list, i++,
            If[i == 1,
              rootApproximation = initialApproximation,
              rootApproximation = Round[z, .1];
             ];
      Sow[z = x /.
               FindRoot[Evaluate[list[[i]]] == function[list2[[i]]],
                {x, rootApproximation}]]]
```

But doing something iteratively like this is new to me in Mathematica, and I feel there must be a better way. For one thing, it defines global variables. Can one use `Module[]` or `Fold[]` or some other functions to make this better?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123583/using-findroot-to-track-moving-bessel-functions-zeros

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `NDSolve` to trace a solution by differentiating the equation:

```
eqn = f == n^2/(n + 1) Exp[I a n];

{sol} = NDSolve[{D[eqn /. n -> n[a], a], n[1] == 1}, n, {a, -10, 10}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];
```

Or by also using the `"Projection"` method, which when coupled with `InterpolationOrder -> All`, gives a better approximation.  The code below gives a single-precision approximation.  Uncomment the options to get a double-precision approximation.

```
Block[{f = n^2/(n + 1) Exp[I a n] /. {n -> 1, a -> 1}},
  {sol} = 
   NDSolve[{D[eqn /. n -> n[a], a], n[1] == 1}, n, {a, -10, 10}, 
    Method -> {"Projection", 
      "Invariants" -> {eqn /. n -> n[a] /. Equal -> Subtract}},
    InterpolationOrder -> All(*, AccuracyGoal -> 24,
    PrecisionGoal -> 24, WorkingPrecision -> 32*)]
  ];
```

Check the residual of the equation:

```
Block[{f = E^I/2},
   Table[eqn /. n -> n[a] /. Equal -> Subtract /. sol, {a, -10, 10, 0.1}]
   ] // Abs // Max
(*  2.73044*10^-9  *)
```

Visualize the trace of the root:

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[n[a]] /. sol, {a, -10, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], 
   Table[Tooltip[Point[ReIm[n[a]] /. sol], a], {a, -10, 10}]}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]