# Force NDSolve to choose given branch at a critical point

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, event-detection

I am trying to find the solution of `f[x,y]==0` by integrating along the curve starting from a point (`vars1`):

```
f[x_, y_] = y*(y^2 - x + 1);
vars = {x, y};
varsOt = Through[vars[t]];
vars1 = FindRoot[f[x, 0.5], {x, 0.5}]~Join~{y -> 0.5};
sysDAE0 = {(D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] /. Thread[vars -> varsOt]).D[varsOt, t] == 0, 
  Norm[D[varsOt, t]] == 1, (varsOt /. t -> 0) == (vars /. vars1)};
{solx, soly} = NDSolveValue[sysDAE0, vars, {t, -3, 2}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -.1, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100], 
  ParametricPlot[{solx[t], soly[t]}, {t, -3, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

All the root curves are in blue, while the result of the above integration is in red:

[image]

Actually, I'd like to choose another branch; instead of take the right part of the $x$-axis, I'd like to catch the left part. To do so, I started by defining a function detecting the critical point (the norm of the gradient of `f`) in order to trigger `WhenEvent`. Then, I ask to choose a change the sign of `x'[t]` when the critical point is detected, hoping it would push the integration to the left of $(1,0)$. But it fails: the integration remains unchanged and still goes to the right of $(1,0)$. Any idea?

```
critical[x_, y_] = Norm[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}]];
{solx, soly} = 
 NDSolveValue[
  sysDAE0~Join~{WhenEvent[critical[x[t], y[t]] < 10^-5, 
     x'[t] -> -x'[t]]}, vars, {t, -3, 2}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

**Edit** To answer some of the comments, here is an example function, which requires the specified `Method`:

```
f[x_,y_] = y(9.77516 + 56.827 y^2 + 142.095 y^4 + x^2 
(-31.1394 - 162.744 y^2 - 299.61 y^4) + x (9.88476 + 65.3474 y^2 + 180.768 y^4))
```

Running the `NDSolveValue` from above returns:

```
NDSolveValue::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. 
Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.
```

Note that in that case, `NDSolve` computes the left branch... Then how can I get the right one (in a robust manner)?

---

**Side notes** on the equations I chose (answering to xzczd and Chris K's comments): I'd like to solve $f(x,y)=0$. Let's rewrite it $f(X)=0$ with $X=[x\ y]^\top$. Since I wanted to use the efficient `NDSolve` and the `WhenEvent` method and get an `InterpolatingFunction`, I instead looked for $t\mapsto X(t)$ such that $f(X(t))=0$. This implies that 
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f(X(t))=\nabla_X f(X(t))\cdot X'(t) = 0$$
for some initial conditions $X(0)$ such that $f(X(0))=0$. This gives one (differential) equation on $X$, so the system is undertermined; it can be completed with the following condition: $\|X'(t)\|=1$.

Comment: I have to believe the solution you get has to do with where the approximate step lands at the singular point. `MaxStepFraction -> 0.00001` gives a different solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Indeed, but how to ensure it goes in a given direction? Do you know what's wrong with my `WhenEvent`?

Comment: This is a typical problem of a phase transition theory. The solution is degenerated. The degeneration can be removed by an introduction of a small "field" acting "in the direction" of one of the solutions: `f[x_, y_] =y*(y^2 - x + 1)-h` and assign `h` to a small value. The closer you are to the bifurcation point the smaller `h` needs to be. The estimate is `h<<Abs[x - 1]^(3/2)` (see 1. L. D. Landau and E. M. Lifshitz, Statistical Physics., 3 ed. Pergamon Press, Oxford, 1985, Chapter XIV, Section 144)

Comment: Continuation. Another approach is to use a differential equation instead of the algebraic one. Indeed, if you consider the equation `y'[t]==-y[t]*(y[t]^2 - x + 1)`, you will find that your desired solution of the algebraic equation represents a fixed point of this differential one. That is any solution will converge to those solutions that are stable. At `x<1` these are `+Sqrt(1-x)` and `-Sqrt(1-x)`. You may fix which of them will be chosen by the numerical process by choosing the initial condition, say, `y[0]>0` to choose the positive one or `y[0]<0` otherwise.

Comment: Continuation: Here the penalty is that the relaxation time diverges in the point `x=1` as it should be (see E. M. Lifschitz and L. P. Pitajewski, Physikalische Kinetik. (1990), Chapter XII, Section 101) and the closer you are to this point, the longer must be the calculation time.

Comment: Re `WhenEvent`: I would think that at each step `x'[t]` is calculated from the ODEs, so reseting `x'[t]`, if it has any effect at all, has one only for one step.  It's also possible that at no step is the norm less than `10^-5` (if the steps were too large).

Comment: Does your real problem also suffer from a pitchfork bifurcation?

Comment: @MichaelE2 "It's also possible that at no step is the norm less than 10^-5 (if the steps were too large)." Exactly, this can be proved by adding a `Print` in `WhenEvent`, a possible work-around is to use `critical[x_, y_] = PiecewiseExpand[Norm[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}]], Reals]; With[{mid = D[critical[x[t], y[t]], t]},……WhenEvent[mid < 0,……` instead. However this causes another problem, which I've no idea about the reason and how to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"` is unavoidable?

Comment: @ChrisK Yes (but it is not exactly a parabola).

Comment: @xzczd I'm not sure, but when I get rid of I get an error recommending the use of this method. If you have a solution which works without this, feel free to share an answer all the same.

Comment: Well, without an example that reproduces the warning you mentioned, I'm afraid I can't give effective answer. Which warning did you encounter?

Comment: Is your real problem also a single function like `f[x, y] `?

Comment: @ChrisK Yes; see edit with a more realistic function.

Comment: Well, I think the solution for the new added function is just 2 disjoint curves?

Comment: @xzczd I also don't see the pitchfork in the new function.  Maybe it needs to be multiplied by `y`?

Comment: @ChrisK Yes sorry I had a typo (missing `y` indeed).

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand the goal.  Your `ContourPlot` approach gives the right picture with no problem.  Alternatively, you can get the answer analytically with `Solve[f[x, y] == 0, y]`.  If you really want to follow each solution, I think the `y=0` solution is distinct from the curvy "forks" in the pitchfork.  Would you want to just numerically solve for the curvy forks?  Because I have a technique for that.

Comment: @ChrisK My goal is to get a nice `InterpolatingFunction` going through the path I choose. I could join two `InterpolatingFunction` but it leads to parametrisation issues. Using `Solve` does not work on my real examples, because `f` is really long. What's your trick to get the curvy forks? Dividing by `y`?

Comment: Er…then where does $\|X'(t)\|=1$ come from? Is it arbitrary?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, it's arbitrary (you could replace 1 with another positive number). But you need an additional condition to define the parametrization uniquely.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the `ntdv` warning (actually in *v9.0.1* I only got `ndsdtc`) and turn to the desired branch we need to

1. modify the 2nd equation a little to avoid `Abs` and `Sqrt`.
2. set a more distinct triggering condition for the event.
3. modify the event to `x[t] -> x[t] + 10^-2`.

Notice I've used `NDSolve` instead of `NDSolveValue` because `NDSolveValue` will only return one solution, which isn't the desired one.

```
f[x_, y_] = 
  y (9.77516 + 56.827 y^2 + 142.095 y^4 + x^2 (-31.1394 - 162.744 y^2 - 299.61 y^4) + 
     x (9.88476 + 65.3474 y^2 + 180.768 y^4));
vars = {x, y};
varsOt = Through[vars[t]];
initx = 1/2; inity = 1/2;
vars1 = FindRoot[f[x, inity], {x, initx}]~Join~{y -> inity};
sysDAE0 = {(D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] /. Thread[vars -> varsOt]).D[varsOt, t] == 0, 
   PiecewiseExpand[Norm[D[varsOt, t]], Reals]^2 == 1^2, 
   (varsOt /. t -> 0) == (vars /. vars1)}
contour = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -.1, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100];
critical[x_, y_] = PiecewiseExpand[Norm[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}]], Reals];
{solx, soly} = 
  With[{mid = D[critical[x[t], y[t]], t]}, {x, y} /. 
    NDSolve[{sysDAE0, WhenEvent[mid < 0, x[t] -> x[t] + 10^-2]}, 
      vars, {t, -3, 2}][[2]]];
Show[contour, 
 ParametricPlot[{solx[t], soly[t]}, {t, -3, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: On MMA 11.0, `NDSolve` returns a function defined over `{0.,0.}`. Without the `WhenEvent`, it selects the left part. Now, if I add `Print[...]` in `WhenEvent`, as such: `WhenEvent[mid < 0, Print["blahblah"]; x[t] -> x[t] + 10^-2]`... it selects the right part... (and prints about a hundred `blahblah`).

Comment: @anderstood Glad to see another bug of _v11_. (……) Just tested on Cloud, this can be circumvented by adding `"DetectionMethod" -> "Sign"` in `WhenEvent`.

Comment: I'm testing the robustness of the method. How would you get the bottom (curved) branch? I changed `x` to `y` in `x[t] -> x[t] - 10^-2`, it returns no error but the branch is not a solution curve, even for different values of the constant.

Comment: @anderstood I'm afraid there won't be a easy (as you expected) way to go to that branch, just observe the result of `WhenEvent[mid == 0, {x[t] -> 0.844231, y[t] -> -0.5, "RemoveEvent"}]` and you'll understand what I mean. BTW, sorry for my poor math, but why can the corresponding differential equation of a curve be obtained in this way i.e. `…(D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] /. Thread[vars -> varsOt]).D[varsOt, t] == 0, 
  Norm[D[varsOt, t]] == 1…`?

Comment: Yes, funny (or hopeless, depending on the point of view :)). Regarding the maths, see bottom of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to numerically get the "curvy forks" of the pitchfork in the second example, using a pseudo-arclength continuation function I hacked together earlier.  First, define `TrackRootPAL` from [the edit in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104694/6358) and define your `f[x,y]`.  Then get an initial point on the track of interest using `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[f[0.9, y] == 0, {y, 1.5}]
(* {y -> 0.693003} *)
```

Then follow it with `TrackRootPAL`:

```
tr = TrackRootPAL[{f[x, y]}, {y}, {x, 0.5, 1.1}, 0.9, {0.693003},
  NDSolveOpts -> {AccuracyGoal -> 7}]
(* {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.741048, 1.05351}}, <>]},
  {y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.741068, 1.05351}}, <>]}} *)
```

That `AccuracyGoal` setting took some fiddling to get right.

Finally `Plot` the results:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. tr], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can get the other branch (in this case, trivially `y=0`) by using a different starting point.

Comment: I think this ends up similar to your approach, but with a different set of equations to solve: `sysDAE0 = {f[x[t], y[t]] == 0, 
  Norm[D[varsOt, t]] == 1, (varsOt /. t -> 0) == (vars /. vars1)}` instead of `sysDAE0 = {(D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] /. Thread[vars -> varsOt]).D[varsOt, 
     t] == 0, 
  Norm[D[varsOt, t]] == 1, (varsOt /. t -> 0) == (vars /. vars1)}`.  Why did you set `D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]` equal to zero?  I'm curious about, but not particularly familiar with this approach, so would appreciate any insights.

Comment: @anderstood oops, forgot to include your handle on my previous comment

Comment: Sorry for my late answer; for the math question, see edit. Regarding your answer: how can you be sure that it will return the curve, and not "bifurcate"?